# If $C$ is a closed subspace topology of $X$, and $S$ is closed in $C$

Tags: general-topology

Then $S$ is closed in $X$. Here is what I could show:

Clerly $C\setminus S$ is open in $S$, so by the definition of subspace topology, there exists $U\subset X$ such that $U$ is open in $X$, and $(C\setminus S)=C\cap U$. Then clearly $S\cap U=\emptyset$.

But how does that lead to $S$ closed in $X$?

Similarly how do I prove the same thing for open sets?

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ is closed in $C$ then exists a set $F$ closed  in $X$ such that $S=C \cap F$

So $S$ is an itersection  of two closed sets in $X$ thus it is closed in $X$

For the second question take $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclideian topology.

and $C=[0,2]$  and $S=(1,2]$ then $S$ is open in $C$ because $S=C \cap (1,3)$ but $S$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I don't understand why there exists a closed set $F$ in $X$ such that $S=C\cap F$?

Comment: @SidCaroline..https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closed_Set_in_Topological_Subspace.

Comment: The claim you want to prove is the corolary stated there..

Answer (score 0):

Note that a similar case doesn't hold for open sets. For example if you assert that for a closed subspace $C \subseteq X$ of $X$, that $S$ open in $C$, implies $S$ open in $X$, this assertion is false by the folloing counterexample.

Take $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $C = [0, 1]$, let $U = (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2})$, then $U \cap C = (\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ is open in $C$, but $U \cap C$ is not open, nor closd in $X$.